# What does OBJECT[x] mean?

Tags: javascript

I have found some sourcecode on a javascript project but couldn't understand a part of code that looks like this:

```
   keystate= {};
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    **keystate[event.keyCode] = true;**
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
delete keystate[event.keyCode]
});
```

The first problem I do not understand is the brackets that come after declaring of the object and then especially what the "= true" means? And a more ambigous question would be: is this a part of OOP (object oriented programming)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets just allows you to [access a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) by having its name in a string (rather than in an identifier as you would use in dot notation).

The `=` is an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment).

`true` is a [boolean literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Boolean_literals).

These are all equivalent.

```
foo.bar = "something";
foo["bar"] = "something";
var property = "bar"; foo[property] = "something";
```

Comment: Does this add the keycode of the current event as a property in the keystate object? If so what does this do? When a key is pressed ad it's keycode as a property in the keystate object and set it to true?